# Creating a variable template to display a database content

Tags: php, variables, for-loop

I'm working on a database website currently and part of the project is to display the content of a database in a custom form using pixels to position the various fields.

I am however having trouble getting the code to work as the way I'm creating the form doesn't seem to work in a php tag, but It requires a WHILE loop in order to continue running until the database field is empty.

I'm only including the relevant code section so as to not clog up the post, all my coding is segmented so I can isolate bugs.

```
<?php 

$usernameh = 20;
$units = "px";

for ($x=0; $x<=2; $x++) {
$pix=$value . $units;

<div style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:20px;width:100px;height:20px;z-      index:5;text-align:left;">
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;">Field Name:</span></div>


$value += 150;
}
?>
```

The idea is to substitute the 20px on the first line of the divcommand with $pix so that with each iteration the value increases by a set amount and separates out the entries.

I'm very new to php coding, as in only really started 2 weeks ago. I'm sure there is a simple solution to this but I'm not sure what question to ask Google to get the response I'm after.

I hope my problem makes sense. The database is in MySQL but all that is fine, its just the formatting I'm struggling with. Even without using a variable in the formatting code the script crashes while the php tag is in effect.

Can anyone offer any advice on where my problem is or suggest another alternative to this.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to break out of PHP `?>` before HTML and then switch back to PHP `<?php` before more PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break out of PHP `?>` before HTML and then switch back to PHP `<?php` before more PHP code

```
$value = 20;
$units = "px";

for ($x=0; $x<=2; $x++) {
$pix = $value . $units;
?>

<div style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:<?php echo $pix ?>;width:100px;height:<?php echo $pix ?>;z-      index:5;text-align:left;">
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;">Field Name:</span></div>

<?php
$value += 150;
}
```

Or for the HTML you can echo it from PHP:

```
echo '<div style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:' . $pix . ';width:100px;height:' . $pix . ';z-      index:5;text-align:left;">
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;">Field Name:</span></div>';
```

Comment: This code will let me print the first entry, but it wont then print the additional ones for each iteration of the loop and im not sure why, I copied the code straight into my test file but It only produced 1 field rather then 3. Any suggestions?

Comment: There were some issues with your vars that I fixed in the edit, however it did and does loop and print 3 times.

Comment: Cheers! I thought I had corrected those variable mismatches after the post, but your edit above works! Thankyou